Animate child object in animated root object in Unity3D
I'm attempting to add animation to the Erika object. However, when I try to do so, the camera shakes in-game due to the existing move animation in NCGS_VAKTA. How can I resolve this issue?
Objects Hierarchy

Timeline

I try to add Erika following position to NCGS_VAKTA, but it not work well
